# Send message to bot from web service

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm launching a web page from my .NET bot. The page interacts with the user from one of our back end systems. Once the interaction is over I need to message the bot with a status update - it sits in a context.Wait whilst awaiting that message.

Currently the bot is using the Facebook channel and launches the page via the Facebook Url button but ultimately it will need to work across multiple channels.

From the web site I can easily send messages which go to the user but despite having spent hours searching and trying different mechanisms I haven't found a way to send a message to the bot.

Latest attempt based on https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d1/df2/_conversation_reference_ex_8cs_source.html, (cr has cached conversation details):

```
string MicrosoftAppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"];
            string MicrosoftAppPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"];

            var account = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword);
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(cr.serviceUrl);

            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(cr.serviceUrl), account);

            Activity activity = new Activity
            {
                Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Recipient = new ChannelAccount
                {
                    Id = cr.bot.id,
                    Name = cr.bot.name
                },
                ChannelId = cr.channelId,
                ServiceUrl = cr.serviceUrl,
                Conversation = new ConversationAccount
                {
                    Id = cr.conversation.id,
                    IsGroup = false,
                    Name = null
                },
                From = new ChannelAccount
                {
                    Id = cr.bot.id,
                    Name = cr.bot.name
                },
                Text = "Test send message to bot from web service"
            };

            try
            {
                await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var s = ex.Message;
            }
```

But no combination of From / Recipient seems to send to bot.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and that you guys can tell me what it is!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of sending a message to a bot from another application.  In this case I was doing this from a web API which was a proxy intercepting messages from the user and sending them to the bot. Not included in this code is how to construct an activity, but it looks like you have that part sorted our already.  Note that in this secondary application I was using `Bot.Builder` so I could use activity objects and other features.

```
//get a token (See below)
var token = GetToken();

//set the service url where you want this activity to be replied to
activity.ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:4643/api/return";

//convert an activity to json to send to bot
var jsonActivityAltered = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity);

//send a Web Request to the bot
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    //add your headers
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

    try
    {
        //set where to to send the request {Your Bots Endpoint}
        var btmResponse = client.UploadString("http://localhost:3971/api/messages", jsonActivityAltered);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

to get a token:

```
private static string GetToken()
{
    string token;
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";
        values["client_id"] = "{MS APP ID}";
        values["client_secret"] = "{MS APP SECRET}";
        values["scope"] = "{MS APP ID}/.default";

        var response =
            client.UploadValues("https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token", values);

        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(responseString);
        token = result.access_token;
    }

    return token;
}
```

Response object class:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public int ext_expires_in { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}
```