# How can you send a message with a new conversation with Bot Framework v4 in C# inside a timer (every x minutes)

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I need to send a message to a bot user when something change in a Database (inside timer every x minutes). 
How i can send mensaje this way without an active conversation?
I need a basic sample in Bot Framework v4.0.

in the previous version I had a route that could be run as a web service, using the service URL of the BOT.

I appreciate any support you can offer.

Comment: What bot? What user? This really needs code for context so we can understand where you're at and the specific technical problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i have a BOT using bot framework v4, which is OK for respond message from any user. 
But I need to send a message at any time, without a conversation. 
I have searched everywhere and I have not found an example of how to do it.

Comment: You can use the typing activty to send a reply to user after a predefined time. Please follow the concept at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0, even though it is for v 3.0 the concept remains the same. Once you get the concept you can use the Typing Middleware to implement it. The MW is available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.Typing/

Comment: This sounds related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117793/proactive-interruptions) about sending proactive messages from an Azure Function. You can probably set up a route and follow the same approach @Drew Marsh recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i review this options today.

Comment: Did that approach work for what you were trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, this example don't function for my problem. Is functional for other circunstancies ,but in my case not. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to start/continue a conversation with a user who has previously talked to the bot before?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently trying to send a message daily to a user to advise of utterences that need to be investigated.

Comment: Hi, Billdr.  Yes i find a solution. Send me your email and i send the function i create.